# Number of stochastic nodes and identifiability in JAGS

Tags: bayesian, jags, winbugs, rjags, hierarchical-bayesian

How does JAGS count the number of stochastic nodes? I assume that the number of "observed stochastic nodes" are the data points and the "unobserved stochastic nodes" are the parameters, right? Does that mean, that, when the number of unobserved nodes exceeds the number of observed nodes, my model is not identified? And is this always the case? JAGS tells me, that I have 6084 observed stochastic nodes and 9072 unobserved stochastic nodes. Do I have an identifiability issue? When I count the parameters and data points, I get totally different numbers. So, how are the nodes counted in JAGS?